# Anko toast() method causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when called from Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, toast, android-toast, anko

I'm having following error when I'm calling toast("Toast's message text") from Android Fragment:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getActivity()Landroid/app/Activity; in class Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' appears in name-of-the-file-classes.dex)

I'm using Anko v0.9.1 and Kotlin 1.0.6

What might be the cause of this crash? Standard Android Toast works just fine. Also toast() function works inside Activities.

Comment: use this Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I stated in my questions that standard Android Toast works without problems. But I would like to know why Anko's "toast()" extension method doesn't work in this case.

Comment: what is your implementation of toast() method

Comment: It is not my implementation, it's Anko: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: toast("text") in fragment's button onClickListener :) (normal Toast works in the same place)

Comment: File a bug on anko Github and use standard Toast API for now.

Comment: @JanSlominski, I have the same error and have created issue https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/328

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is very strange, probably it is a bug.

But next works for me

```
activity.toast("Toast's message text")
```

or

```
context.toast("Toast's message text")
```

Comment: Took me embarrassingly long to figure out I was calling this from a fragment and needed context/activity

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it inside a class (an adapter, for example), surely you have  to get the activity first (context)

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
                { view ->
                    view.getContext().toast("Message")
                }
        )
```